# What is -moz-border-radius? -CSS

Tags: css

What is

```
-moz-border-radius:
```

I really have no idea what it is, and I can't find answers on stackoverflow, google, or anywhere. I'm new to web dev and I tried using this and opened up firefox, and there is no real difference. Nor if I open anything else. Also what about

`-webkit-border-radius` or anything that begins with `-webkit`

Comment: If you copy "moz-border-radius" to http://google.com and try to search - you'll find your answer.

Comment: It's the `border-radius` CSS property, prefixed for Mozilla and Webkit.  It gives rounded corners.

Comment: If you use google, you have to remove the "-" prefix, since that tells google to EXCLUDE that term from the query.

Answer (score 3):

They are vendor prefixed properties, a type of [vendor specific extension](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#vendor-keywords)

They are used to implement experimental versions of features before they are standardised.

> An initial dash or underscore is guaranteed never to be used in a
>   property or keyword by any current or future level of CSS. Thus
>   typical CSS implementations may not recognize such properties and may
>   ignore them according to the rules for handling parsing errors.
>   However, because the initial dash or underscore is part of the
>   grammar, CSS 2.1 implementers should always be able to use a
>   CSS-conforming parser, whether or not they support any vendor-specific
>   extensions.
>
> Authors should avoid vendor-specific extensions

Answer (score 3):

Well anything starting with a - prefix is for a specific browser.

- -moz is for firefox
- -webkit is for chrome and safari
- -o is for opera
- -ms is for internet explorer

Border radius is simply just to round the corners of an element. You can set the value to 5px and you will see the difference. Here is a fiddle to show the property: http://jsfiddle.net/Ps4mN/

```
border-radius: 5px;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is important to realize browser compatibility, and most import *backwards* compatibility. Mozilla, in it's past used it's own unique methods of parsing CSS. They also, because of this, were a little behind on new standards in CSS and had to add them later down the road. Adding prefix's to these attributes gave them a way to highlight their 'new' implementation of already released CSS as a 'new and improved' vision of whats already out. See [branding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brand).

Because of this, however, it caused a lot of issues with compatibility between developers. Deciding what browsers to develop for, or how to optimize for one specific brand. Which furthered it notoriety as well as it's revenues.

Only recently has some browsers caved into following standards of CSS, such as `border-radius:`

However, do to this war, which is still being raged, you need to keep in mind a lot of people don't use the browsers you are using. In fact some 25% of all computers online still run Windows XP as well as Internet Exploder (I'm sorry, Internet Explorer or something like that)! And there is no easy way of supporting rounded corners there besides fun workarounds.

Take a look at this article about cross compatible borders for new and old browsers **[right here](http://jonraasch.com/blog/css-rounded-corners-in-all-browsers)**. Mind you `border-radius:` will work in newer version of Mozilla, but not older ones. It will also run on current version of most web standard browsers. Just it's always good to keep some legacy code in for older browsers.